# How do I play flash animations in flash builder by using the flash container or components?

Tags: flash, flashbuilder4

Do you know how to run flash animations in flash builder without creating flash project? Only use a flash container or components to integrate animations in flash builder.. Help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display an animated swf within a Flex app, you can use the [SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) component:

```
<mx:SWFLoader source="@Embed(source='path/to/movie.swf')" />
```

Comment: I would like to use button to control how it play. For instance, every time the play button has pressed, it should play from the begin or reset to begin of the animation. Help please...

Comment: Thats a separate issue - you should post a new question